# exception on inserting single quote in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, exception

I am facing problem that. when I insert single quote in text field. on insertion it give exception of incorrect syntax near that particular field. why is it? does single quote has special meaning to sqlserver?

what if user what to enter word like don't , it's, or sometime by mistake enter single quote in start then it give exception. is there any sol to handle this? if single quote has issue with sqlserver.. then how to deal it?

Comment: Show us some code how you are passing parameters to your SQL statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server strings are enclosed (typically) in single quotes, so a single quote within a string will result in an error if you don't escape it prior to it being INSERTed.

Single quotes simply need to be doubled up, so the string `Will''s World` would result in `Will's World` making it's way into the data.

Comment: -1 because you provided a dirty way to fix the problem, SQL parameters are the solution

Comment: can it is possible that I convert ' quote to its hex value,,, like in HTML for space we use &nbsp ,,, same with single quote and on retrieval we have to convert it again?

Comment: @Johann - I have to hold my hands up and agree - this is a dirty fix to the OPs problem.  A SqlCommand with parameters is far cleaner.

Comment: @will is it possible as I said?

Comment: @Touseef - don't even try that - possible but a waste of time.

Comment: ok can u code your answer? u said that will''s world would result will's.. so it mean we have to convert user single quote in double on insertion and then on retrieving we have to again convert it into single... because we have to display user the same info as he inserted.

Comment: INSERT'ing a string Will''s World will result in Will's World being put into the database - on retrieval you will get Will's World and not a string with a doubled-up quote.

Comment: @will I understand that you are saying that inserting will''s will's to put in db. but it give exception,, that's why I am asking, how to handle single quote inserted by user? definitely we have to make in such form that it could be insert able. I am asking the way to convert. do u get my point?

Comment: If you _must_ inject the string directly into SQL then you need to escape it up with a simple function of your own devising, or with String.Replace("'", "''").  Please look into using SqlParameters.

Answer (score 9):

use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead of string concatenation

This kind of expressions is worst thing you can do in your code, because at first you will have problem with data type convertion, and second the doors of [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is opem for hackers

```
string someQuery = "Select * from SomeTbl Where SomeTbl.SomeColumn = '" + tbSomeBox.Text+ "'" ;
```

Instead of that just use this

```
string someQuery = "Select * from SomeTbl Where SomeTbl.SomeColumn = @param";
SqlCommand someCommand = new SqlCommand(someQuery, conn);
someCommand.AddParams("@param",tbSomeBox.Text);
...
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You will need to escape single quotes in SQL statements.

For example:

```
'don''t'
```

Comment: -1 because you provided a dirty way to fix the problem, SQL parameters are the solution

Comment: The person posting the question was asking whether single quotes mean something special in an SQL Server query. I answered that question which is yes. If everybody just uses high level libraries without understanding what happens behind the scenes then they are missing important information.

Answer (score 0):

In SqlServer, if you want to insert string with quotes, use quotes twice before and after the string. For example you want to insert `'Hello'`, so insert it like `'''Hello'''` provided the field you want to insert in has string datatype like varchar etc.

Comment: -1 because you provided a dirty way to fix the problem, SQL parameters are the solution

Comment: There is not a single solution to the problem, I described one of the solutions.

Comment: Yes you did, and I gave my appreciation and explained my down-vote. :)

Comment: Its you right to put your view point, but I dont see the reason of down voting.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnection string")) { 
    con.Open(); 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); 
    string expression = "(newsequentiali'd())"; 
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
    cmd.CommandText = "Your Stored Procedure"; 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Your Parameter Name", 
                SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = expression;    
    cmd.Connection = con; 
    using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
    { 
        if (dr.Read()) 
        { 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: -1 because you provided a dirty way to fix the problem, SQL parameters are the solution

Comment: and on retrieval of data? again I put this replace function with every string?

Comment: Not required to format it again. It is for sending query to database only.

Comment: Thanks Johann. It is working through parameters and no need to do manual formatting of the parameter. Below is the code.     using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnection string"))
{
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
string expression = "(newsequentiali'd())";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "Your  Stored Procedure";
cmd.Parameters.Add("Your Parameter Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = expression;
cmd.Connection = con;
using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
if (dr.Read())
{
}
}
}

Comment: @SQL, please edit your answer with the new code and I'll remove my down-vote

Comment: Thanks for knowledge sharing.